# Coordinating Actions on Multiple Logstash Instances

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have recently been looking into setting up an elasticsearch cluster, and was curious how to coordinate actions amongst multiple logstash instances. I need to regularly index data from a database, which I can do using the jdbc input plugin. My problem is that I am unsure of how to coordinate this action across multiple logstash instances. If, for example, I run the action on only one instance, and that instance goes down, the data will not be ingested into elasticsearch. On the other hand, if I run the action on multiple instances, I will be protected from the failure of any one instance, but I will have duplicate data in elasticsearch.

I believe using a load balancer along with logstash-forwarder or filebeat would avoid this problem, because the data would get sent evenly to all instances. Unfortunately, I can only query the database from my logstash instance, I can't set up logstash-forwarder or filebeat on the database server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an ftp{} input filter that I wrote that suffers the same problem you describe.  Right now, it's only installed on one logstash machine and would require an ansible run to move it to another logstash in case of system failure.  Not ideal.

I'm starting to dislike logstash for gathering data, and am leaning towards external programs for gathering and logstash-forwarder for shipping.

In my case, I'll rewrite the ftp gatherer as a stand-alone script that puts files into a directory watched by logstash-forwarder.  Of course, there's no inherent redundancy there, either, but at least I can restart my logstash instances at will.

Comment: It's too bad there isn't more support for redundancy built in. I really like the tool because it saves me from having to write a script using an elasticsearch client for each source, and more support for redundancy would really cinch it for me. I appreciate all the help. I think I may post an issue to github about this problem to see what the developers say.

Comment: Your comment reminded me that they promised a more "cluster-like" config for logstash2, but I don't know how far they made it.

Comment: From [github](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/4187): "There are plans to have Logstash cluster multiple instances to allow this sort of thing. I don't know if we have a timeline for it yet though".